# 403 Sling Post servlet

Tags: aem

I'm following this blog [post](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/how_to_upload_animageviaslingpostservlet/). But I'm getting 403 error in AEM 6.1. 
I do not want to change in 'Apache Sling Referrer Filter'. 
I think this error is coming because of CSRF token which I can get by calling /libs/granite/csrf/token.json

But how can I add this CSRF token in this form header? Or is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201101/aem-403-forbidden-occurs-when-call-a-post-servlet/39490339#39490339

Answer (score 1):

you can add the csrf token with the standalone tag

```
<cq:includeClientLib categories="granite.csrf.standalone" />
```

you can add this on every page you use a form, or maybe you have a masterpage witch inherits to every page

the csrf token is a hidden field, before the formular is sent. it looks like

```
<input type="hidden" name=":cq_csrf_token" value="4a6sd4f6as4df6as.a5s4df6a4sdf674asd96f"></input>
```

Comment: clientLibs I cannot use, because this html file is outside of AEM, its just a something.html file.

Comment: I even added hidden type in html form but result is same.

Comment: if you are outsite of aem I dont know how to do. I just know that you can get a token from "/libs/granite/csrf/token.json". And then you have to add id to the request Header, maybe you have to add it as ":cq_csrf_token", but im not sure.

Comment: You can set the csrf token as a HTTP request header instead of putting it in the body of the POST request. The header name should be called 'Csrf-Token'.

Answer (score 0):

As your page is outside AEM, one way to handle this globally would be to include the granite csrf JS in your application and modify it to point to your AEM token.json url. This script takes care of form posts, AJAX calls at a global level.

Secondly, this script does some checks related server url hosts and context paths. So you will have to disable those as well. It's a fairly simple JS to modify. 
I know this is not an ethical approach but using AEM in this manner is also not a normal usecase :)

Comment: Sling has the functionality to use POST servlet in this way, so it is ethical way :) and i resolved this by calling HTTP POST through java code with proper header.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate your solution and add as an answer to help others. Originally I thought you were trying to post from an html page.